# Fragments and Notifications: Target different Activities from Notification; depending on screen configuration

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-notifications

### Question:

How to decide what `Activity` a `Notification` should launch if the target  might depend on the configuration (screen size, orientation etc); as is often the case when one uses `Fragment`s?

---

### Details:

Let's consider the [NewsReader sample](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) that demonstrates how to use `Fragment`s to produce an app that plays well with multiple screen sizes and orientations. This app is structured as follows:

- A `HeadlinesFragment`.
- An `ArticleFragment`.
- A "main" activity (`NewsReaderActivity`). In dual pane mode, this activity contains both the fragments. In single-pane mode, it only contains the `HeadlinesFragment`.
- An `ArticleActivity`. This activity is only used in single pane mode; and it contains the `ArticleFragment`.

Now, suppose I were to enhance this app to add a background `Service` that listens for news updates and notifies the user via status bar notifications whenever there are new news items. A reasonable requirements listing might read like so:

1. If there are multiple news updates, clicking on the notification should always take the user to the headlines list.
2. If there's only one update, clicking on the notification should open up the brand new news article.

Note that these requirements translate to different target activities depending on current configuration. In particular,

1. Requirement (1) in either mode = `NewsReaderActivity`.
2. Requirement (2) in dual-pane mode = `NewsReaderActivity`.
3. Requirement (2) in single-pane mode = `ArticleActivity`.

What would be an elegant way to achieve (2) and (3) above? I think one can safely rule out the possibility of the `Service` probing for the current configuration to decide what activity to target with the `PendingIntent`.

One solution I thought of was to skip (2) and always do (3) - i.e., always launch `ArticleActivity` if there's only one news update. This snippet from ArticleActivity looked promising:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    //...
    // If we are in two-pane layout mode, this activity is no longer necessary
    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    //...
    //...
}
```

This code ensures that if one is viewing the `ArticleActivity`, but switches to a configuration where it is no longer required (for example from portrait to landscape); then the activity simple closes.

However, this won't work in our case since the intent will have the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`  flag set; we would have created a new task, and there is no "previous" activity on the stack. So, calling `finish()` would just clear the entire stack.

So, how does one decide what activity to launch from a notification, if the activity to launch depends on screen configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really good question!

> I think one can safely rule out the possibility of the Service probing for the current configuration to decide what activity to target with the PendingIntent.

I'd agree that it would be preferable to keep UI decisions at the UI layer, but having the service make the decision would certainly be an expedient choice. You might use a static method on a UI layer class to keep the decision code technically outside of the service (e.g., a static `createArticlePendingIntent()` method on `NewsReaderActivity` that the service uses to build its `Notification`).

> So, how does one decide what activity to launch from a notification, if the activity to launch depends on screen configuration?

Use a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` for `NewsReaderActivity` in your `Notification`, with enough extras that `NewsReaderActivity` knows that it is in this "show the article" scenario. Before it calls `setContentView()`, have it determine if `ArticleActivity` is the right answer. If so, `NewsReaderActivity` calls `startActivity()` to launch `ArticleActivity`, then calls `finish()` to get rid of itself (or not, if you want BACK from the article to go to `NewsReaderActivity`).

Or, use a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` for `ICanHazArticleActivity` in your `Notification`. `ICanHazArticleActivity` has `Theme.NoDisplay`, so it will not have a UI. It makes the decision of whether to launch `NewsReaderActivity` or `ArticleActivity`, calls `startActivity()` on the right answer, and then calls `finish()`. The advantage over the previous solution is that there is no brief flash of `NewsReaderActivity` if the end destination is `ArticleActivity`.

Or, use the `createArticlePendingIntent()` option I mentioned in the first paragraph of my answer.

There may be other options as well, but those are what come to mind.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: 1) The problem with having the `Service` make the decision is that the configuration could change _after_ the service has posted the notification to the status bar; which means the service needs to keep updating the notification every time there's a config change. Plus I'm not sure how to access `R.bool.dual_pane` resource from outside a UI layer.

Comment: Option 3) looks promising (`Theme.NoDisplay`): Route all notifications through a common no-UI `Activity` that takes further decision. I'll have to grok the "Tasks and Back Stack" document to weigh all implications though; since I'm still unclear on how an `Activity` launched from a notification fits in the back stack. And how a no-UI activity behaves in the back stack! I'll leave the question open for the time being to see what other suggestions I get.

Comment: @curioustechizen: Agree with your "1)" point. `R.bool.dual_pane` you would get via `getResources().getBoolean()` from any `Context`. "And how a no-UI activity behaves in the back stack!" -- if you use this approach, you would `finish()` the no-UI activity after calling `startActivity()`, and so it would not be on the back stack.

Comment: Ah you're right. I missed the point about calling `finish()` after the no-UI activity does its job.

Comment: How long is the flash if you launch the new Activity in onCreate()? It feels like the simplest solution to me, but depending on how long the flash is it may not be very nice.

Comment: @alexanderblom: That will depend on the device (CPU speed, GPU speed, OS version, etc.).

Comment: I went for the no-UI `Activity` approach. I posted another answer with more details of what other approaches I tried.

Answer (score 5):

When I'm using a dual pane/single pane approach in my apps then I'm only using one activity. In this case it means get rid of ArticleActivity. Here's how you could proceed instead:

First off you control the appearance of the fragments by using XML layouts for the different configurations, e.g:

single pane (res/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

dual pane (res/layout-xlarge-land):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In NewsReaderActivity you only need to check which fragments are existing in the layout:

```
boolean isMainFragment = (findViewById(R.id.mainFragment) != null);
if (isMainFragment) {
    mainFragment = new ListFragment();
}

boolean isDetailFragment = (findViewById(R.id.detailsFragment) != null);
if (isDetailFragment) {
    detailFragment = new DetailsFragment();
}

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (isMainFragment ) {
    transaction.add(R.id.mainFragment, mainFragment);
}
if (isDetailFragment ) {
    transaction.add(R.id.detailFragment, detaislFragment);
}  
transaction.commit();
```

Then when you are in single pane mode (detailsFragment not existing) and want to show the details screen then you simply launch the same activity again but include a parameter in the intent to tell which content is needed:

```
void onViewDetails() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewsReaderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("showDetails", true);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In onCreate() of your activity you choose the fragment depending on this parameter:

```
boolean isDetailFragment = (findViewById(R.id.detailsFragment) != null);
if (!isDetailFragment) {
    boolean showDetails = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("showDetails", false);
    if (showDetails) {
       mainFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    }
    else {
       mainFragment = new ListFragment();
    }
}
```

**Now when you finally launch the activity from the notification then you just don't care 
about the current screen orientation anymore!**

Just include the "showDetails" flag in your intent and set it as appropriate, just like it's done in `onViewDetails()`. Your activity will then show both fragments when you are in dual pane mode (you can still do some special behavior if "showDetails" is true), or otherwise when you are in a configuration that requires single pain mode, then the fragment you specified in the "showDetails" flag is shown.

I hope this helps and gives you a good understanding about this approach.

Comment: That's an interesting way to approach `Fragment`s. I had tried [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10051962/570930), although in a different context. The linked SO question has a detailed discussion about this, including pros and cons. That said, I'd prefer to stick with the "standard" way of using `Fragment`s where possible (since it is widely understood). I'd really want to avoid re-doing my `Activity` and `Fragment` design to accommodate the single-`Activity` approach if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The no-UI Activity approach mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784293/570930) is what I decided on. I tried another option, but it did not work out. What I tried was this:

1. In the `Service`, build an `Intent` stack with the `Intent` for `NewsReaderActivity` at the bottom of the stack and that for `ArticleActivity` at the top.
2. Use `PendingIntent.getActivities()` and pass in the stack as created in Step1 to obtain `PendingIntent` representing the full stack.
3. In `ArticleActivity`, we have the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //...
       //...
       // If we are in two-pane layout mode, this activity is no longer necessary
       if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes)) {
           finish();
           return;
       }

       //...
       //...
   }
   ```

So, you first target `ArticleActivity` - which does a sort of self-introspection to decide if it is useful in the current configuration. If not, it simply moves out of the way with `finish()`. Since the `NewsReaderActivity` is already present "before" `ArticleActivity` in the back-stack, this takes you to `NewsReaderActivity`.

This seemed the perfect solution - except for one point which I had overlooked: `PendingIntent.getActivities()` only works with API 11 or above. There is a rough equivalent in the support library: [`TaskStackBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html). One can go on adding Intents to the stack with `addNextIntent()`, and finally call `getPendingIntent()` to achieve something similar to `PendingIntent.getActivities()` (I assume).

However, on pre-HC devices, this will result in only the **top-most** `Activity` from the stack being started in a new task (emphasis mine):

> On devices running Android 3.0 or newer, calls to the startActivities() method or sending the PendingIntent generated by getPendingIntent(int, int) will construct the synthetic back stack as prescribed. *On devices running older versions of the platform, these same calls will invoke the topmost activity in the supplied stack, ignoring the rest of the synthetic stack and allowing the back key to navigate back to the previous task*.

So on pre-HC devices, pressing back from ArticleActivity will still take you back to the task that was running prior to ours. This is not what we want.

I will probably share my project sometime soon. I was also concerned about starting fresh tasks even when I was doing intra-app notifications (for example, a "new news article" notification while I am reading an article). I'll hopefully post that as a separate question.