# Two fragments in one viewpager page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Currently, I use one fragment per viewpager's page through FragmentPagerAdapter very well.
But now I want to use a two panel view inside one viewpager's page for tablet.
Fro example, the left hand side is a list view and the right hand side is a gridview.
Does anybody know How can I achieve that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just don't know how can I return 2 fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter, can you give me some hint?

Comment: Checkout ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter code for example - it's just a view, but it displays number of Fragments. So, all You need - create Your own view (simplier than ViewPager) to work with two fragments using the same approach as ViewPager/FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: You mean I give up using ViewPager and do a custom view myself to work like ViewPager, and it can show two fragment at one page. right?

Comment: no, it could be just one item in ViewPager.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051962/fragment-design-adapting-to-multiple-screen-layouts-by-showing-hiding-fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I use two view in one fragment and control the data myself.
But I noticed There is a new feature in support package and framework so that I can add a fragment inside fragment. See Answer here: [Fragment Inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have something like google market you can create the tow fragmnets independently and then add the code in the adater

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
if (position == 0) {
return(0.5f);
} else {
return (1.0f);       
}
}
```